# Function requires date in quotation marks, how to pull from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel function of the form `=RTWArcValue("7/14/15 14:00:00")`. The argument of the function must be a date and time within quotation marks. I'm trying to automate this to automatically input a date based on a user input into cell `A1`, but I can't figure out how to insert that value into the function argument.

I've tried simply:

`=RTWArcValue(A1)`,    `=RTWArcValue("A1")`,   `=RTWArcValue("""A1""")`,  or even `=RTWArcValue(""""&A1&"""")`. None of these work, and I get an error saying that it is not a correct input to the function.

I've also tried other things such as using `DATEVALUE`.

Does anyone have insight into this? How can I use this function and input a value from another cell while meeting the function requirements? At this point I think it might be just that the function won't allow you to reference other cells for the date input.

I want the input to this function to give the first day of the month. I can symbolically enter the current date by using `=RTWArcValue("Day(Now())")`, which works, but when I enter `=RTWArcValue("Date(YEAR(Today()), MONTH(Today()), 1)")`, I get an error message.

Comment: So it's a UDF and you haven't provided us the code of the function, so how can we help?

Comment: **Help us to help you.**  Post your code.

Comment: I don't know how to provide the code of the function, I didn't write it, and it's included as an add-in to Excel at my work.

Comment: Without knowing what the function is doing, we can't be sure of the way to escape the quotation marks

Comment: Try `=RTWArcValue(TEXT(A1,"m/d/y HH:mm"))` which will take the date/time in `A1` and convert it to a text string and pass that to `RTWArcValue()`.

Comment: This doesn't work either :/ I think it might just be how the function is designed unfortunately.

Comment: At the risk of beating a dead horse, how about `=RTWArcValue(TEXT(A1,"m/d/y hh:mm:ss"))`, which is Mike Fitzpatrick's comment plus `:ss` (seconds)?  (On my system, the `hh`, `mm`, and `ss` are case-insensitive.)

Comment: …  And, if that doesn't work, is there any possibility that you can upload the file somewhere?  Yes, I know, your data are proprietary / top secret / HIPAA, and you can’t release it.  Can you create a blank workbook that has one cell where `=RTWArcValue("7/14/15 14:00:00")` works and another where `=RTWArcValue(TEXT(A1,"m/d/y hh:mm:ss"))` doesn’t work?  Or is the `RTWArcValue()` function defined in an add-on to Excel itself, so it won’t transfer with a workbook?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=RTWArcValue(CHAR(34) & A1  & CHAR(34))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that doesn't work :/